# Basic Matlab Syntax Understanding

Tags: matlab

I am learning Matlab and I see this line and I don't fully understand it. It's not something I can google so any help would be appreciated.

```
size(A([1:3,5:100],:))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
size(A([1:3,5:100],:))
```

Breaking into pieces (from inside out, not repeating things that were already explained):

```
[1:3,5:100]   - elements 1,2,3 and 5,6,7,…100 
A([], :)      - Rows 1,2,3 and 5,6,7,…10 , and all columns, of matrix A
size()        - the dimensions of the object
```

The result will be

```
[99 N]
```

Where N is the number of columns in `A`.  Why `99`? Because we only skip row 4 (and everything after 100). If `A` has fewer than 100 rows, this command will fail.